# Cut a certain string from a biggest one which could have a variable length. (SQL SERVER)

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, substring

I have a small problem with a string that I need to take a specific part of.

I know exactly where it begins but it could have variable lengths, so I can not use SUBSTRING where I have a fixed length of Chars that I could use.

Example:

```
EREF+322345 KARR CUSTOMER1 ....

EREF+3211234 KARR CUSTROMER2....
```

I need to take the number after the `+` sign till the space before the word `KARR` begins.
In the first line it is `322345` ( 6 chars) and in the second it is `3211234` which is 7 chars so the length could be variable.

SUBSTRING doesnt help me in this case because i do not have a fix number of chars what i want to cut of the string.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

This will work :

```
declare @a varchar(255)='EREF+322345 KARR CUSTOMER1'
select substring(@a,charindex('+',@a,1)+1,charindex(' ',@a,1)-charindex('+',@a,1))

-------------------------------
declare @a varchar(255)='EREF+3211234 KARR CUSTROMER2.'
select substring(@a,charindex('+',@a,1)+1,charindex(' ',@a,1)-charindex('+',@a,1))
```

Comment: You're off by 1 there, krish - this will return the space at the end of the number also. Change the space for something else to see what I mean `declare @a varchar(255)='EREF+3211234#KARR CUSTROMER2.'
select substring(@a,charindex('+',@a,1)+1,charindex('#',@a,1)-charindex('+',@a,1))`

Comment: maybe also add some explanation of WHY it works, cos it's just like "wham, here's a block of code"

Comment: where it begins ( the index) is always knows and it is diectly after the " EREF+" and it ends always with the " KARR".The Problem is that i have more than one "+" in the String ( I did not post the whole String in my Example). so i changed it so that i know where it begins ( Charindex 6) and ya as Caius Jard said this will take a char more than i need which is the Space or whatever it is.